# Dataset of US Treasuries outstanding

Tags: data-request, treasuries

I'm looking for a CUSIP level dataset of all outstanding Treasury securities (notes, bonds, bills, TIPS... everything), not just those in the fed SOMA portfolio.  I'm particularly interested in the following fields:

- CUSIP
- Issue Date
- Maturity
- Par Value
- Coupon
- Type

So far, the best I could find is the following dataset which has some limitations:

https://fiscaldata.treasury.gov/datasets/monthly-statement-public-debt/detail-of-treasury-securities-outstanding

There are lots of NULL values for the outstanding amount, and it's tough to make sense of it all.  SIFMA seems to be just summary level as well.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - answering my own question for future readers.  Somewhat confusingly, the Raw Data "Detail of Treasury Securities Outstanding" seems to be missing a lot of data once you download the CSV.  For example, lots of NULL values for balance amounts, maturities, odd formatting etc.

#### Detailed Report

[image]

However, if you switch tabs to "Published Reports" - you can then select from PDF or XLS and get a detailed list of all holdings, in a relatively clean format.

#### Published Reports

[image]